# How to return string array in objective c

Tags: objective-c, arrays, function, return

I am trying to get data from web service and adding it into nsmutablearray,
after that i want to return that array from extern c function.....

for example:

```
@implementation SampleClass

    -(NSMutableArray* ) createArray:
    {
    NSMutableArray *array=[NSMutableArray new];
    //
    //add value in array
    //

    return array;

    }


    @end


    extern 'C'
    {

    //how can i 

    NSArray* returnArray()// this method should return string array
    {
    SampleClass *sc=[[SampleClass alloc]init];
    NSMUtableArray* a=[NSMutableArray new];
    a=[sc createArray];
    return a
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need to use `extern "C"` since Objective-C is a superset of C? You can already use C code without problems.

For your question it depends on lifetime of the array. If the array is retained then this is enough:

```
char *cString = [[array objectAtIndex:i] UTF8String];
```

Otherwise you'd need to allocate a new `char*` for each string, for example by using `strdup`:

```
char *cString = strdup([[array objectAtIndex:i] UTF8String]);
```

Mind that the latter will require you to release memory when you longer need it with `free(cString)`. If you need to return a C array then you will create it before and set values accordingly, eg

```
char** cArray = calloc([array count], sizeof(char*));
```

Comment: thanx for your reply, I am trying to create plugin for unity3d for that i need extern "C"... using this extern "C" i access that in c# code... so i need method in extern "C" which return string array...